# Creating a new page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, frameworks

I'm trying to create a new page in Laravel and I'm not sure what to do in the context of the Laravel framework.
If it was just html, then you just create a new html file. In Laravel, what are all the things you need to do when creating a new page?

Comment: Have a look at this series: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest way in Laravel is to define a route closure, and return a view from it.

In your `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/my-page', function () {
    return view('my-page');
});
```

Then in `resources/views` you create a file called `my-page.php`, or if you want to use Laravel's Blade syntax (you probably do) call it `my-page.blade.php`.

---

Edit: there's now an even easier way to to it. Also in `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::view('/my-page', 'my-page');
```

This will do exactly the same thing as the previous example, without the need for a closure and explicitly calling `view()`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two locations to add New Page to your Laravel project:

1. You have to create an additional route in YOURAPP>routes>web.php file.
2. You have to add PHP file with that name to YOURAPP>resources>views folder. If you want to use BLADE for your project, than you should put name_of_page.blade.php. And you should concider it as a must at the very beginning :).

Now, in routes you should be able to add only first part of the file rather than .blade.php. For example: about.blade.php, you can put in route only about

It should work out of the box :).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this in `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::get('/my-page', function () {
    return view('my-page');
})->name('my-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function now seems to be in the `HomeController.php` file in the `app\http\controllers` directory.

```
public function page()
{
  $information = $this->metadataInformation();

  return view('page', compact('information'));
}
```

While the `routes\web.php` has the

```
Route::get('/page', [HomeController::class, 'page'])->name('page');
```